# Passing a virtual class reference as an argument to constructor

Tags: c++, constructor, polymorphism, header-files

I have defined an abstract class `Algorithm1` in the `.h` file. I want this abstract class, `Algorithm1` to hold the references to some other abstract classes, and to be able to decide exact which ones during the runtime. So my `Algorithm1` holds those references, and I want to be able to pass the exact implementations via the constructor. One exact implementation of `Algorithm1` is class `Algorithm1A` So here is how that looks.

**Algorithm1.h**

```
#include "Interval.h"
#include "OrderedAlphabet.hpp"
#include "Rank.h"

//! Algorithm1 interface
class Algorithm1 {

protected:
    Rank &rank;
    OrderedAlphabet &alphabet;
    std::map<symbol_type, occurence_type> &C; 

public:
    Algorithm1(Rank &r,
               OrderedAlphabet &a,
               std::map<symbol_type, occurence_type> &c):
                rank(r), alphabet(a), C(c) {
    }

};

#endif /* Algorithm1_h */
```

**Algorithm1A**

```
#include "Algorithm1.h"

class Algorithm1A : Algorithm1 {

    std::string uniqueCharsInInterval(int i, int j) {
        rank.rank() // dome something with ABSTRACT rank
    }


    std::vector<Interval> getIntervals(int i, int j) {
        alphabet.getSize() // do something with alphabet - not abstract
        C.find('x') // do something with C - not abstract
    }
};
```

Besides that, my `Rank` class is also an abstract class, but is implemented by the class `WTRank`, `NTRank` and so on. So what I really want is to be able to pass `WTRank` object, but as a `Rank` reference to the constructor of `Algorithm1`.

**Rank.h**

```
#ifndef Rank_h
#define Rank_h

#include "DataTypes.h"

//! Rank interface
class Rank {
public:
    virtual unsigned long long rank(int index, symbol_type symbol)=0;
};

#endif /* Rank_h */
```

And my `WTRank` class is divided into a `.h` and `.cpp` file.

**WTRank.h**

```
#ifndef WTRank_h
#define WTRank_h

#include "Rank.h"
#include <sdsl/wavelet_trees.hpp>

using namespace sdsl;

//! Rank based on Wavelet Tree
class WTRank: public Rank {

private:
    wt_huff<> wt;

public:
    WTRank(wt_huff<> w_tree) {
        this->wt = w_tree;
    }
    ~WTRank();

    unsigned long long rank(int index, symbol_type symbol);
};

#endif /* WTRank_h */
```

**WTRank.cpp**

```
#include "WTRank.h"

unsigned long long WTRank::rank(int index, symbol_type symbol) {
    return wt.rank(index, symbol);
}
```

Now if I want to create an `Algorithm1A` object that implements `Algorithm1` abstract class, and I want to give its constructor needed arguments, I am doing something like this - and getting "No matching constructor error."

```
wt_huff<> wt;
construct_im(wt, str, 1);

OrderedAlphabet alphabet(10);
std::map<symbol_type, occurence_type> C = calculateC(wt, alphabet);
WTRank wtrank = *new WTRank(wt);

Algorithm1A alg = new Algorithm1A(wtrank, &alphabet, &C); // ERROR!!
```

How should this be done in order to have it working?

Comment: What is a 'virtual class reference'?

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but you are leaking memory with those two `new`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Constructors are not inherited. You need to define a constructor on `Algorithm1A` which takes the appropriate arguments.

```
Algorithm1A::Algorithm1A(Rank &r,
                         OrderedAlphabet &a,
                         std::map<symbol_type, occurence_type> &c):
  Algorithm1(r, a, c)
{}
```

Answer (score 2):

Constructors are not inherited by default in C++.  If you have C++11, you can explicitly forward your base class constructors to the derived class:

```
class Algorithm1A : Algorithm1 {
public:
  using Algorithm1::Algorithm1;
  ...
};
```